# Why can I assign a dynamic_array equal to a static_array but not the other way around?

Tags: c++

a dynamic_array = static_array would run fine but when I run static_array = to dynamic_array I get " error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [5]'"

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int static_Array[5];
int *dynamic_Array = new int [5];

int i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    static_Array[i] = i;
    dynamic_Array[i] = i;

}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "static_Array[" << i << "] =  " << static_Array[i] << endl;
    cout << "dynamic_Array["<< i <<"] = " << dynamic_Array[i] << endl;
}

cout << endl << endl << endl;

static_Array = dynamic_Array;

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "static_Array["<<i<<"] = "<<static_Array[i] << endl;
    cout << "dynamic_array["<<i<<"] = "<<dynamic_Array[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess by "dynamic_array" you mean a pointer. pointers are not arrays, however arrays may be implicitly converted to pointers of compatible type.

Comment: A pointer `int*` can point to the start of an array of any size. You don't need to know the size to find the first element. However, you can't be sure a given pointer points to the start of an array of a specific size.

Comment: please show some code illustrating what you mean with dynamic/static array and the initialisations/assignments you do; then we can better comment on it.

Comment: @StephanLechner I have included the code in the post.

Comment: You're leaking memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C++ cannot be assigned, they can just be initialised with a well-defined set of expressions, e.g. with initialization lists.

So the following statements wont't work as they are *assignments*:

```
int static_Array[5];
int array2[5];
int *dynamic_Array = new int [5];

static_Array = dynamic_Array;  // error: static_Array is not a pointer, and it is not assignable
static_Array = array2; // error: static_Array is an array and therefore not assignable
static_Array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };  // error
```

But the following statement works, because it is an *initialisation* done at the time of variable definition; it cannot be repeated later (where it would be an illegal assignment then):

```
int static_Array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
```

When you talk about "dynamic_Array", you actually mean a pointer to an integer, which is not an array. It just points to an integer, or to the first of a sequence of integers, but it is not an array by itself. And you may assign a pointer value, but note that this does not "copy" any array content, it just sets a pointer to an integer:

```
int static_Array[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int *dynamic_Array = new int [5];
dynamic_Array = static_Array;  // OK (apart from leaking memory): lets dynamic_Array point to the first value of static_Array; No copy!

static_Array[0] = 10;
cout << dymanic_Array[0]; // will print 10.
```

Hope it helps.